# Copy one directory to another while retaining its structure

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script

Let's assume I have the following source directory:

```
source/
    subdir1/file1
    subdir1/file2
    subdir2/file3
    subdir3/file4
```

And target directory:

```
target
    subdir1/file5
    subdir2/file6
    subdir4/file7
```

I would like to move (but really move not copy and delete) the content of the source subdirectories to the right target subdirectories so the result looks like this:

```
target
    subdir1/file1
    subdir1/file2    
    subdir1/file5
    subdir2/file6
    subdir2/file3
    subdir3/file4
    subdir4/file7
```

Is there some Linux command to do this or must I write a script myself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use rsync for this.

```
rsync -a sourcedir/ destdir/ --remove-sent-files --ignore-existing
```

For example:

```
mtak@frisbee:~$ find test test2
test
test/subdir1
test/subdir1/file2
test/subdir1/file1
test/subdir2
test/subdir2/file2
test/subdir2/file1
test2
test2/subdir1
test2/subdir1/file3
test2/subdir1/file4
test2/subdir2
test2/subdir2/file3
test2/subdir2/file4

mtak@frisbee:~$ rsync -a test/ test2/ --remove-sent-files --ignore-existing --whole-file 

mtak@frisbee:~$ find test
test
test/subdir1
test/subdir2
mtak@frisbee:~$ find test2
test2
test2/subdir1
test2/subdir1/file2
test2/subdir1/file1
test2/subdir1/file3
test2/subdir1/file4
test2/subdir2
test2/subdir2/file2
test2/subdir2/file1
test2/subdir2/file3
test2/subdir2/file4
```

This is a bit of a hack though, because it will copy the file first and then remove the source file (so it's not like `mv`).

Comment: It is not true. I have tested that and it said that it can not move files because subdirectory of target directory is not empty

Comment: Just like `cp`, if target exists, it will move `source` _under_ `target`, i.e. create `/path/to/target/source/`. It complicates the matters somewhat unfortunately.

Comment: @Trismegistos: Are you sure your `mv` is not alias to `mv` with some options (quite common in some setups)? Can you show the exact error?

Comment: No mv is plain command.
LC_ALL="C" mv a/* b/
mv: cannot move `a/d1' to `b/d1': Directory not empty

Comment: Indeed, you are right. I didn't notice the names of the subdirectories were the same.  I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Trismegistos Did my update answer your question?

Comment: @mtak moving file is not the same as copying them and then removing. So no it is not the answer.